# Pear won't uninstall

Tags: php, pear, uninstallation

Recently I successfully uninstalled pear using the following command:

`$ sudo pear uninstall pear`

So I recently reinstalled it, but I botched the installation and I want to start over (once again). This time, when I run the above command, pear gives me this message:

`pear/pear not installed`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Voted to move to http://www.serverfault.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PEAR is just a bunch of php scripts. To uninstall it manually just remove `/usr/share/php/PEAR` (the path can vary on distribs)

Comment: Good point. I found the directories I needed to remove, and also needed to remove `/etc/.pearrc` (in case anybody else is wondering). Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Refer to the correct way to install and uninstall pear:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Comment: Thanks but I've checked the docs and it doesn't say anything about uninstalling.

Comment: Right on that page it tells you how to install Pear using wget and php... it takes two minutes.

Comment: @MatthewRMiller Yes, but I am not trying to install it at this point, I am trying to uninstall it. Which I did. (I just manually deleted the directories per zerkms's suggestion.)